# Converting Zero-Terminated String To D String

Tags: d, c-strings, string-conversion, null-terminated

Is there a function in Phobos for converting a zero-terminated string into a D-string?

So far I've only found the reverse case `toStringz`.

I need this in the following snippet

```
// Lookup user name from user id
passwd pw;
passwd* pw_ret;
immutable size_t bufsize = 16384;
char* buf = cast(char*)core.stdc.stdlib.malloc(bufsize);
getpwuid_r(stat.st_uid, &pw, buf, bufsize, &pw_ret);
if (pw_ret != null) {
    // TODO: The following loop maybe can be replace by some Phobos function?
    size_t n = 0;
    string name;
    while (pw.pw_name[n] != 0) {
        name ~= pw.pw_name[n];
        n++;
    }
    writeln(name);
}
core.stdc.stdlib.free(buf);
```

which I use to lookup the username from a user id.

I assume UTF-8 compatiblity for now.

Answer (score 6):

There's two easy ways to do it: slice or std.conv.to:

```
const(char)* foo = c_function();
string s = to!string(foo); // done!
```

Or you can slice it if you are going to use it temporarily or otherwise know it won't be written to or freed elsewhere:

```
immutable(char)* foo = c_functon();
string s = foo[0 .. strlen(foo)]; // make sure foo doesn't get freed while you're still using it
```

If you think it can be freed, you can also copy it by slicing then duping: foo[0..strlen(foo)].dup;

Slicing pointers works the same way in all array cases, not just strings:

```
int* foo = get_c_array(&c_array_length); // assume this returns the length in a param
int[] foo_a = foo[0 .. c_array_length]; // because you need length to slice
```

Comment: if you want a string then use idup which creates an immutable duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Just slice the original string (no coping). The $ inside [] is translated to str.length. If the zero is not at the end, just replace the "$ - 1" expression with position.

```
void main() {
    auto str = "abc\0";
    str.trimLastZero();
    write(str);
}

void trimLastZero (ref string str) { 
    if (str[$ - 1] == 0) 
        str = str[0 .. $ - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to strip away the trailing zeros and convert it to a string:

```
char[256] name;
getNameFromCFunction(name.ptr, 256);
string s = to!string(cast(char*)name);   //<-- this is the important bit
```

If you just pass in `name` you will convert it to a string but the trailing zeroes will still be there. So you cast it to a char pointer and voila `std.conv.to` will convert whatever it meets until a `'\0'` is encountered.